# Search MultiDimensional Array For String & Get the key

Tags: php, arrays

I am using the PDO Api, and using the `fetchAll()` returns a Multiple Dimensional Array; This snippet below is just a test scenario; I just want to know if it's possible.

```
$LeUsername = "BravoSlayer"; 
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username='$LeUsername'");
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
print_r($result);
$ArraySearch = search_array($result, $LeUsername);
```

Output is as below:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [ID] => 1 [0] => 1 [Username] => bravoslayer [1] => bravoslayer [Password] => thisisatest [2] => thisisatest ) )
```

I want to search through the multi-dimensional array to return the key. IN this case it will be 0 so I can just associate another variable variable for $Array1 = $Array1['0']  so from then I can do:

```
$Username = $Array1['Username'];
```

Comment: whytf do you want to do it?

Comment: @onlineapplab.com  I believe the OP is getting at searching through a multidimensional array to search for a string; if the string is found, it'll return the key of the first nest of the array

Comment: @DarylGill
I'm rather interested why he would like to initialize $Array1 and use $Array1['Username'] instead of using $result[0]['Username'] Also there is a username in the SQL WHERE condition so each record will have the same username.

Comment: @onlineapplab.com I guess it'll easier for him instead of `$result['0']['Username']` using `$result['Username']`   I guess anyway. Until we get a reply from the OP; we'd not know; Kinda interested in the method though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by your question. You could search the primary array within a `foreach` loop and use `in_array` to return the correct array.

Use this as your reference.

```
function Search_Array($Array, $SearchDilema)
    {
        foreach ($Array AS $CheckKeys)
        {
            if (in_array($SearchDilema, $CheckKeys))
            {
                return $CheckKeys;
            }
            else
            {
                $ErrorMsg = "No Results Found! Check Your Search Dilema"; 
                return $ErrorMsg;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thankyou. This worked perfectly. `$Test = Search_Array($result, $LeUsername);` to call that function?

Comment: your loop will search only the first element of the array

Comment: @onlineapplab.com Sorry for the delay. This will return a multi dimesional array with the query structure, yes.. It will only search through the first element, but if the array is `0 => array("test","find") 1=> array("test2", "find2")`  it will change the array foreach of the elements, searching the inner array.. in this case `array[1][x]` then `array[2][x]` etc and returning the correct array passed in the function

Comment: You need to move 'return $ErrorMsg' out of the foreach loop to achieve this.